# behavior of PdfPage.flush()

Tags: itext7

what exactly does PdfPage.flush(true) do?  Does SmartMode (or any other setting) affect the behavior?  For many cases, i want to leave the page editable for as long as possible, so never worried that the PDF document was assembled in memory until `document.close()`.  But when generating very large files (tens of thousands of pages), memory is becoming constrained.  I was naively hoping that `PdfPage.flush(true)` would write the content stream to disk and free up memory, but calling `flush(true)` only seems to write a couple of bytes to disk.

I guess the more general version of my question is "how do we efficiently merge lots of documents into a single, very-large document? (itext7)" but not being highly proficient w/ the PDF spec itself i'd also like to better understand what's actually going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flush()`, when called on layout objects, forces those objects and their children to draw (== write) their contents to the writer's outputstream. The reason why you only see a couple of bytes being written when manually calling flush() is because the default `Document` constructors already set iText to flush aggressively by overloading the relevant constructors:

```
/**
 * Creates a document from a {@link PdfDocument} with a manually set {@link
 * PageSize}.
 *
 * @param pdfDoc   the in-memory representation of the PDF document
 * @param pageSize the page size
 */
public Document(PdfDocument pdfDoc, PageSize pageSize) {
    this(pdfDoc, pageSize, true);
}

/**
 * Creates a document from a {@link PdfDocument} with a manually set {@link
 * PageSize}.
 *
 * @param pdfDoc         the in-memory representation of the PDF document
 * @param pageSize       the page size
 * @param immediateFlush if true, write pages and page-related instructions
 *                       to the {@link PdfDocument} as soon as possible.
 */
public Document(PdfDocument pdfDoc, PageSize pageSize, boolean immediateFlush)
```

As for advice on the general question:
There isn't really some sort of iText function or configuration that makes the entire progress magically faster and more efficient, but there are some tricks you can do outside of iText:

1) Allocate more resources, obvious and often not feasible.

2) Do multi-stage batch processing: merge 10-files into 1 in step X, continue with merging those files in step X+1. In general, the 1 big-file will be smaller than the 10 files seperatly, because of the possible re-use of resources such as fonts and images.

3) Run the merging process at times the resources it takes up aren't needed anywhere else, e.g., at night, over lunch etc.

Edit:
As for why PdfPage#flush() only writes a couple of bytes to the contentstream, that depends on the input document, but it most likely points towards a page being flushed that either has mostly text content or a lot of shared resources. SmartMode should limit the amount written to the outputstream that a page flushes, as long as the page contains resources that have been copied before.

Comment: for clarity, i'm only seeing a couple of bytes written out IN TOTAL (i.e. immediateFlush isn't doing anything easier...the _entire_ output file is only a couple of bytes long instead of Mb's).  I appreciate the attempt at the answer, but i don't think it addresses my `PdfPage.flush(boolean flushContentStream)` question.  Attempting to follow the code path up to PdfObject.flush(), it appears there may be a different behavior w/ flushing indirectReferences (but i can't stitch everything together in my head).

Comment: @jameygraham *"for clarity,..."* - you should really update the question as it currently appears to say something different. And if there only are a few bytes in the result PDF, I would assume the procedure either is stopped by an exception or your code does something wrong, like grabbing the PDF before its `PdfDocument` is closed.

Comment: @jameygraham I've tried to address your initial question about `PdfPage.flush`. There's some complex interactions in the core due to various optimizations though, so I might've missed some things. If you are merging large files and your output is only a couple of bytes, you might have another problem altogether. Might, since those 1000-page files might be horribly inefficient monstrosities, but without access to both in and output I can't help you any further. That said, my general remarks for the 2nd, more general question still stands.

Comment: @samuel - ok...so it sounds like there's an expectation that page flushing _should_ in fact be writing a page's content-stream(s) to disk (which is not the behavior i'm observing).  If true, that in itself seems sufficient to answer my question (i did get tripped up a bit by the name change of the parameter....from what i think was `flush(boolean flushXObjects)` [700] to `flush(boolean contentStreams)` [701]).   I'll open up a support incident with a specific example.