# How can I add page numbers to my iText7 Pdf after im done generating it?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

```
private void addPageNumbers(Document doc)
{
    var totalPages = doc.GetPdfDocument().GetNumberOfPages();
    for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
    {
        // Write aligned text to the specified by parameters point
        doc.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph(string.Format("page %s of %s", i, totalPages)),
                        559, 806, i, TextAlignment.RIGHT, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
    }
    doc.Close();
}
```

this is the code i tried, but I get the following exception:

> iText.Kernel.PdfException: "Cannot draw elements on already flushed
> pages."

I need to add the page numbers in the end because after generating the content of the pdf I generate a table of contents and move it to the beginning of the document. Therefore i only know the page numbers after generating all the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText by default tries to flush pages (i.e. write their contents to the `PdfWriter` target stream and free them in memory) early which is shortly after you started the next page. To such a flushed page you obviously cannot add your *page x of y* header anymore.

There are some ways around this. For example, if you have enough resources available and don't need that aggressive, early flushing, you can switch it of by using a different `Document` constructor, the one with an extra boolean parameter `immediateFlush`, and setting this parameter to `false`.

Thus, instead of

```
new Document(pdfDoc)
```

or

```
new Document(pdfDoc, pageSize)
```

use

```
new Document(pdfDoc, pageSize, false)
```

---

<sub>[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41718122/1729265) is a related answer.</sub>